# Google Maps not showing in my app , and appear in another app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary

i am facing a strange problem with google maps ,
i  have followed all the instructions but map doesnt appear in my app and says this message :

> E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

the same steps i did on a new project for testing purpose using the same API Key (not restricted) and the maps show up .

would you help me with the possible reasons ??

Edit :

Below is MapActivity :

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;
Button select ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select);

    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

            finish();
        }
    });





}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Marker in Delhi"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(HAMBURG));
}}
```

And XML :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MapActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/select"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@color/coldGreen"
    android:text="@string/select_this_place"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.551"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"></Button>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
package="*.*.app" 
android:versionCode="30"
android:versionName="1.2.9">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>


<dist:module dist:instant="true" />

<application
    android:name=".Dayir"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

 <activity android:name=".activities.MapActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

There the App Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "*.*.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
   optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.github.developer-shivam:Crescento:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.DanielMartinus:Stepper-Touch:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.sephiroth74:NumberSlidingPicker:v.1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
implementation project(path: ':searchablespinner')


 }
```

And this is the LogCat :

```
   2019-12-16 13:42:23.149 23386-23386/*.*.app I/Timeline: Timeline: 
   Activity_launch_request time:1606688503
2019-12-16 13:42:23.181 23386-23386/*.*.app W/ActivityThread: 
handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@b1c360f
2019-12-16 13:42:23.243 23386-23386/*.*.app I/Google Maps Android API: 
Google Play services package version: 19629028
2019-12-16 13:42:35.549 23386-23386/*.*.app E/SchedPolicy: 
set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2019-12-16 13:42:35.553 23386-23386/*.*.app D/onActivityResult: try to 
set location
2019-12-16 13:42:35.553 23386-23386/*.*.app D/result: ok excuted 
2019-12-16 13:42:37.715 23386-23386/*.*.app I/Timeline: Timeline: 
Activity_launch_request time:1606703069
2019-12-16 13:42:37.745 23386-23386/*.*.app W/ActivityThread: 
handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c18f5a1
2019-12-16 13:42:37.819 23386-23386/*.*.app I/Google Maps Android API: 
Google Play services package version: 19629028
2019-12-16 13:42:37.999 23386-23888/*.*.app E/Google Maps Android API: 
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an 
authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

**EDIT :**

i found that the colnfiliction is due to SSL Verfier i use in my App , i have added the following domain **clients4.google.com** in the exception list .
i hope this may help someone :)

```
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            //  Log.d("verify_url","is => "+arg0);
                if(arg0.equals("www.yourMainDomain.com") || 
                    arg0.equals("clients4.google.com") ){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please post your maps activity, manifest and app-level build.gradle files so that we can look into this issue from our side? Also please share the full logcat.

Comment: @evan  .. please check edit , any thing else ?

Comment: Thank you I'll test your code and get back to you in a few hours.

Comment: Just posted my findings in answer below, please keep me posted on your testing and investigation. I look forward to your update and happy to investigate further from my side if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your code and it works without problem on my end using an emulator. All I changed was setting the activity as launcher and removing the third-party dependencies.

Please test the below code, which is basically your own code without dependencies:

MapActivity

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;
    Button select;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select);

        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Marker in Delhi"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(HAMBURG));
    }
}
```

activity_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.551"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"></Button>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.myapplication"
    android:versionCode="30"
    android:versionName="1.2.9">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If the above code works for you then you can rule out network-related or emulator/device-related issues (if it doesn't then please look into those).

Thereby the root cause is either those library dependencies I removed or your API key. Make sure that you added your unrestricted API key to your google_maps_api.xml files (in both debug and release folders), that Maps SDK for Android is enabled on your project and that your billing account is in good standing.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Well, thank you for your generous help , i did follow your steps , but still the same issue is present !

Comment: I see, in that case the issue must be network or emulator/device related because the above code works just fine. Which one are you using and have you tried to run the app across multiple devices/emulators? Is google play services up-to-date on those? Also do please use an unrestricted api key that belongs to a project that has billing enabled. Do you get any different errors or the same one?

Comment: Dear , i discovered the issue , that was due to the SSL verifier . i have added the domain clients4.google.com to the exception list ans it solved the problem , thank you :)